# I have small problem about using playwright record to test (Assertion)

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, playwright-java

[image test datetime checker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSBUK.png)

In picture, I use record function to auto wrtie test code, but I can't print out line "await expect(page.getByText('dd/mm/yyyy is correct date time!')).toHaveCount(1); "

How can I print the line above?

I watch through video on youtube but I can't find the way to auto print line expect

Comment: What do you mean by "print the line above"? What you've included is an assertion. If it fails, it will be printed in the output. If it passes, depending on the reporter, you won't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this feature does not exist. You can check [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14913).